Not able to remove jenkins plugin
I was trying to update Allure plugin from jenkins.
It failed with error message
Failed to load: Allure Jenkins Plugin (allure-jenkins-plugin 2.30.3)
 - Failed to load: Script Security Plugin

Now i am not able to uninstall plugin from ui or disable it.
Any help is appropriated

You can remove it from the $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/ directory

If you are using older versions off jenkins and you are not allowed to uninstall plugins from ui here are few options :
option1:

remove plugin from jenkins's root dir's plugin path : $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/
restart jenkins

new version of jenkins has option to manually remove plugin
